# Heroku is giving me this error but Xampp is not

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku, xampp, localhost

```
$raw_query = "('{$this->input->post('phone')[0]}')";
```

Heroku is giving me error on this line. It says "syntax error, unexpected [, expecting }". This weird cause xampp is not giving me this error. Is it actually an error or is there something wrong with Heroku?

Comment: did you try removing the [0] and see if you get a error still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, please do following

```
$tmp = $this->input->post('phone');
$raw_query = "('{'.$tmp[0].'}')";
unset($tmp);
```

It is caused of PHP version. (as far as I remember)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is php version difference. Your xampp running php 5.4.x and heroku running might be 5.3.x.

Function array dereferencing has been added in 5.4 e.g. foo()[0].

Reffrence: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php